# Why does my Apache server show a 500 on every other refresh?

Tags: apache

My lab has an Apache server `A` that proxies requests to other servers inside a firewall. I have a web application running on another Apache server `B`. The problem is that my web app returns a 500 error on every other refresh. Meaning:

```
Refresh => 200 ok
Refresh => 500 error
Refresh => 200 ok
Refresh => 500 error
...
```

I'm not a sys ops person and have no idea where to start looking. Any thoughts on what would cause this?

Comment: You can start looking at the logs. `500` basically means: check the logs ;-)

Comment: There are no errors in `B`'s logs. `A`'s logs say there is a connection error, but it to the wrong port, i.e. not the port specified in our proxies configuration file. Oddly enough, I just noticed that when Chrome web inspector is open, the page refreshes fine. Could this be an issue with sessions?